# R: Generating series of dates into another variable using start.date and end.date variables in R

Tags: variables, date, transformation, generate-series

I have one dataset consists start_date, end_date and var_string. Here I want to create new dataset consists individual dates into '`DATE`' starting from `start_date` to `end_date`, and '`var_string`' should contain repeated string as follows start and end date. Here is my sample data:

```
start_date  end_date    var_string

1/2/2012    5/2/2012    Apple

6/2/2012    4/3/2012    Sony

6/2/2012    4/3/2012    Dell
```

so I want to transform this dataset in R as follows:

```
Date        var_string

1/2/2012    Apple

2/2/2012    Apple

3/2/2012    Apple

4/2/2012    Apple

5/2/2012    Apple

6/2/2012    Sony

.           .

.           .

.           .

4/3/2012    sony

6/2/2012    Dell

.           .

.           .

.           .
4/3/2012    Dell
```

and so on..

So please help me in getting new dataset in R as mentioned above.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I want to transform this in R.

Comment: How is SSIS involved? Or should that tag be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and get the output using the following small program, but I need it in more effective way in small lines of R code. Anyone could help me.

temp=data.frame()

nds1=data.frame()

bn=data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(data))

{

nds=rbind(data.frame("Date"=seq(as.Date(data$Start.Date[i], "%d-%m-%Y"),

as.Date(data$End.Date[i], "%d-%m-%Y"),by="days")))

nds1=rbind(nds1, nds)

temp=rbind(temp,nrow(nds))

bn=rbind(bn,data.frame("Promo.Type"=rep(data$Promo.Type[i],temp[i,1])))

}

final=data.frame(nds1, bn)